# Any SaaS solution to host a private maven repository

Tags: maven, nexus, archiva

Is there any SaaS solution to host a maven repository?

I know I can host it myself on Nexus or Archiva or Artifactory, just want to know if there are affordable providers that permit to host a few dependencies for a low cost without having to install the repository on your own.

I'm looking for a online maven repository host that can garantee a good availability and that keeps the artifacts private.

Comment: You can publish private maven artifacts with https://jitpack.io. The way it works is that JitPAck builds private GitHub repositories and host them in its own private maven repository

Comment: [deps.co](https://www.deps.co) also offers private Maven repositories to publish and retrieve JARs and other Maven artifacts.

Comment: CloudRepo provides [private maven repositories](https://www.cloudrepo.io/private-maven-repositories.html) for exactly this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [CloudBees](http://www.cloudbees.com/) offers private Maven repositories. You should give it a try.