# Add feed4j dependency in pom.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I cannot add a dependency in pom.xml for feed4j.jar

[image]

When I select a dependency for feed4j I get feed4junit but not the feed4j.

[image]

When I add a dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>feed4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>feed4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I get an error

> Missing artifact feed4j:feed4j:jar:1.0

As a result when I try mvn clean install I get an error

> package it.sauronsoftware.feed4j does not exist

Any help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, i found the answer [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-a-custom-maven-settings-xml) but feed4j is not included in the [repository.jboss](http://repository.jboss.org/) that's why I used the [pentaho-releases](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/pentaho-releases/).

Answer (score 0):

Feed4j is not in the Maven central repository. You have several options:

1. Use a Maven repository which has the feed4j artifact available. You can set up your own Nexus or Artifactory.
2. Include the jar file in your project and use the maven system scope (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305679/maven-and-eclipse-a-reliable-way-to-add-non-maven-or-external-jars-to-a-project) for an example how to use it)
3. Install the dependency manually in your local Maven repository. [Here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) is a short tutorial how to do that.

Comment: Dominik what I'm trying to achieve is to push my app to heroku. I tried <systemPath>C:\Users\Alex\.m2\repository\feed4j.jar</systemPath> and worked fine locally but got an error when I tried to push. I also tried <systemPath>${JAVA_HOME}/lib/feed4j.jar</systemPath> and got an error in pom.xml Missing artifact feed4j:feed4j:jar:1.0

Comment: same error with <systemPath>${basedir}/target/feed4j.jar</systemPath>

Comment: In this case you should create your own Maven Repository. Take a look at this thread for your options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095589/any-saas-solution-to-host-a-private-maven-repository